# Mysterious behaviour of a HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I was trying to inflate & add `RelativeLayout`-s into a `HorizontalScrollView`. The `RelativeLayout` (thumbnail.xml) has a `TextView` as a descendant, the problem was that the `TextView` wasn't showing; neither were any other Views.

---

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        LinearLayout contents = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.contents);

        //LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        // changed to WRAP_CONTENT but doesn't seem to make a difference
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout thumbnailLayout = (RelativeLayout)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.thumbnail, null);
        contents.addView(thumbnailLayout, layoutParams);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- ① -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

thumbnail.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- ② -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- BEWARE: You MUST resize the drawable 'null_thumbnail' when thumbnails get resized! (2015.08.31) -->
    <!-- ④ -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="This ImageView only exists in order to fix the ratio of the whole layout."
        android:src="@drawable/null_thumbnail"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <!-- IF YOU REMOVE THE BACKGROUND ATTRIBUTE, THE TEXTVIEW DISAPPEARS!? -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="128">

        <!-- dummy -->  
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4" />

        <!-- ③ -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="27"
            android:text="Can you see this?"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="50sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

I figured out that adding any drawable as the background solves the problem, but I'm still confused. Is it by design or am I mistaken?

I tried refactoring the root of `R.layout.thumbnail` with `LinearLayout`, `ScrollView` but the only one matters is `HorizontalScrollView`.

---

**UPDATE:**

[image]

(Note the architecture isn't actually defined inside a single .xml file.)

I want to show dynamic images which are of a same dimension (*WIDTH* × *HEIGHT*) as background of a RelativeLayout (②) and a TextView (③) on it. ② is a child of a LinearLayout, ①, which is the only child of a HorizontalScrollView.

In order to keep the aspect ratio of every ②, I put a *WIDTH* × *HEIGHT* transparent drawable (`null_thumbnail`) in ④, set the size of ② to wrap content of ④.

Phew, hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Both ImageView and LinearLayout inside the RelativeLayout has layout width and height set to `match_parent`

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

while the RelativeLayout has its layout width and height set as `wrap_content`, this creates a interdependency which would result in strange behaviours like what you met.

**Edit:**
wrong for me, you override the width and height of RelativeLayout in program as **match_parent**, however the parent of RelativeLayout, the LinearLayout `contents` has width is **wrap_content**, this is where the actual interdependency is causing the problem.

Need to know your expected look of the final product to actually suggest how you should correct it.